# Why is my SelectedValuePath property of my comboBox misbehaving?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm struggling to find why my `SelectedValuePath` isn't causing my combo box to pass a double to my view model property `DelayLength`. When I change the combo box selection during execution the combobox turns red and gives the error :

```
ConvertBack cannot convert value '[2 Seconds, 2]' (type 'KeyValuePair`2'). BindingExpression:Path=DelayLength; DataItem='TestViewModel' (HashCode=62605785); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: DoubleConverter cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].
```

Is there something simple I'm missing because I believe I'm following documentation correctly?

**Window.xaml**

```
    <ComboBox Width="120" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0"
              DisplayMemberPath="Key"
              SelectedValuePath="Value"
              ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLengths}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding DelayLength}"/>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding DelayLength, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>

</StackPanel>
```

**Window.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new TestViewModel();
    }
}
```

**TestViewModel.cs**

```
class TestViewModel : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase
{
    public Collection<KeyValuePair<string, double>> AvailableLengths
    {
        get
        {
            if (_availableLengths == null)
            {
                _availableLengths = new Collection<KeyValuePair<string, double>>()
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, double>("None", 0),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, double>("0.5 Seconds", 0.5),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, double>("1 Second", 1),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, double>("2 Seconds", 2),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, double>("3 Seconds", 3)
                };
            }

            return _availableLengths;
        }
    }

    private double _delayLength;

    public double DelayLength
    {
        get { return _delayLength; }
        set
        {
            _delayLength = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DelayLength));
        }
    }

    private Collection<KeyValuePair<string, double>> _availableLengths;
}
```

Comment: SelectedValuePath is supposed to be used in conjunction with SelectedValue, not SelectedItem.

Comment: @Clemens perfect. That fixes it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectedValuePath` can not be used with `SelectedItem`. You have to use `SelectedValue`.

**Customized summary from MSDN:**

> The SelectedValuePath property provides a way to specify a
>   SelectedValue for the SelectedItem. The SelectedItem represents an
>   object in the Items collection and Control displays the value of a
>   single property of the selected item. The SelectedValuePath property
>   specifies the path to the property that is used to determine the value
>   of the SelectedValue property.